# Codeigniter return result and row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In the Model class I use `return $query->row();` to return single rows and `return $query->result();` when returning multiple rows.

On a single page I have to return single rows and multiple rows from 2 separate tables.

Table `users` contains general information like the user name, full name, and email address.
Table `user_links` contains links submitted by the respective user and has multiple rows for each user.

My query

```
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('user_links', "user_links.user_id = users.user_id");
        $this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('user_links.user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
```

In my controller I load the query in my view by

`$data['row'] = $this->User_model->user_read($user_id);`,

`$user_id` being the 3rd URL segment containing the unique user id.

Finally, in my view I retrieve rows by `echo $row->first_name;`

This works for single rows but how can I create a `foreach` loop for user links? The goal is to avoid loops for single rows and use them just for retrieving multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get both the user data as well as user_links data with a single query while avoiding iterating through it to get the user's data. While this may be possible using result_array, I would advise against it since you will get 0 results when there are no entries in user_links for that particular user.

My suggestion is that you use two queries, one to get the user from the user table, another to get user's links from user_links table. This will also help you avoid joins.

Comment: Thanks! I was using 2 queries before and sending both from controller to view but joins seemed more professional.

Answer (score 6):

This is psuedo code but you can probobly do something like this

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('user_links', "user_links.user_id = users.user_id");
    $this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('user_links.user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->row(); 
    }
    elseif ($query->num_rows() > 1)
    {
        return $query->result_array(); //This returns an array of results which you can whatever you need with it
    }
    else 
    {
         //Add some logic to handle if there are zero results
    }
```

Comment: Rows equal 1 from one table and more than 1 for the other table so having the tables joined, I would have to return both row() and result(). I think that if statements should be added in the view.

Comment: I must not have understood your question then, but I think it's good practice to avoid if statements in your view and either handle them in the controller or the model.

Comment: Thanks Odnxe! +1 for if statement suggestion. I will look into implementing if statements in my model and see if it's better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell what you want.

You want a function that checks if you're passing a `row()` or a `result()` and treat them accordingly.

In my opinion your code would be easier to read (and maintain) if you just passed everything as a `result()`. And do check if the set is empty to show a nice message to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for some of the other features already provided by CI's Active Record: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

For what you are doing it sounds like using the built in function result_array would work. You use it like so:

TAKEN FROM LINK ABOVE

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Isn't `result_array` the same as returning `result()` from the model? The object format looks neater than pure array.

Comment: Yes it is the same thing only in array format. I must have misunderstood what you really were asking. Could you clarify exactly what you want?

Comment: I want to return both `row()` and `result()` from my model to controller to view and in view retrieve data from the database using either `echo $row->some_value;` for 1 row or create loops via the `result()` function

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace this line:

```
$this->db->join('user_links', "user_links.user_id = users.user_id");
```

With this one:

```
$this->db->join('user_links', "user_links.user_id = users.user_id", 'left outer');
```

Join in codeigniter uses `INNER JOIN` by default but in some cases if there is no data in `user_links` it returns nothing so u can use `LEFT JOIN` in your frame work CI it used like i mentioned above.